# MongoDB All values in an array should be less than a value

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have an document with an embedded array of documents. i.e. 'key' => array(...)

Is it possible to create a query so that for some value in the embedded array, all of them are $lt some value?

So like this:

```
{
'key.value' : { $lt : 5.0 }
}
```

Problem there is as soon as one is $lt then it matches which i dont want, I want all should be less than 5.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You just want to find which values are less than 5 or you want to reduce larger values to 5 and let the smaller ones stay the way they are?

Comment: i basically want to get all documents that have all their key.values less than 5. Note: 
{
'key.value' : { $lt : 5.0 }
}
contains other fields. eg:
{
name : Bob,
'key.value' : { $lt : 5.0 }
}

Answer (score 8):

How about using the $not operator?  Specifically, match all the values you don't want, then get the opposite.  So something like:

```
 {
 'key.value' : { $not : { $gte : 5.0 }}
 }
```

Would get all the documents which don't have values in the array greater than or equal to five, which is what I think you want, right?